# WCF RIA and LightSwitch HTML - item add/edit

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

I'm new to WCF RIA and LightSwitch HTML so I'm probably missing something.

I'm making small web app for smart phones. My start screen got list of items that are retrieved via WCF RIA service. Data that is retrieved is similar to data that is in one of my tables in database. (I needed complicated computed property so this was the most clean way I could do it). Now I would need to make screen to add new and edit clicked item.

One possible way (which I would prefer) is to make a new details screen with query filtered by id, then pass id to property and show that screen/tab. Problem is I don't know how to get clicked/selected item ID.

As far as I know I can't get it from DOM in this way:

screen.Xxx.selectedItem.ID

because my data item is query not property.

Any suggestion is welcome... I'm getting out of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to retrieve id of selected item...

screen.MyProperty = screen.details.properties.GetAllLeistungserfassungScreenItemsByFilter(query).value.selectedItem.LeistungserfassungID;

Now I will make detail tab screen and load data filtered by "MyProperty", hopefully save will work from the box.

See ya around!